# memory usage problem

Tags: c++

I am working on optimizing the memory usage of my codes and I found a problem that I do not understand. Please let me know what you think.

Code:

```
typedef map <pair<string, int>, vector<pair<int, float> > > TDM;

void parsefile (TDM & my_map, string in_file); // parse input file and put it in the data map
float CheckMemUsage (void); // check memory usage by extracting /proc/self/stat info


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  TDM my_map;
  string infile = "xxx";

  printf ("INFO: Memory usage before parse file: %.2fM.\n", CheckMemUsage ());
  parsefile (my_map, in_file);
  printf ("INFO: Memory usage after parse file: %.2fM.\n", CheckMemUsage ());

  for (TDM::iterator it=my_map.begin(); it!=my_map.end(); ++it) {
    vector<pair<int, float> > ().swap (it->second);
  }
  TDM ().swap (my_map);
  printf ("INFO: Memory usage after delete map: %.2fM.\n", CheckMemUsage ());
}
```

The report of this program:

```
INFO: Memory usage before parse file: 13.46M.
INFO: Memory usage after parse file: 203.53M.
INFO: Memory usage after delete map: 132.59M.
```

In the function "parsefile", I only use string, vector, pair, map stuffs, without new any memory. So after this program, I assume that only my_map is in memory. After deleting my map, the memory usage should return to before parsing file status (13.46M). But it still reports a 132.59M. What is this 132M for? Is there sth wrong in my program?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you have deallocated memory from the heap, which is what `std::map` uses behind the scenes to implement its storage, does not mean the memory is returned to the operating system during execution of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So can the non-returned  memory be used for further operation without asking the OS for more memory? Further more, the input gzip file is just 12MB, is the required memory (203MB) too large? Any idea to reduce the memory usage?

Comment: Yes; the heap's memory allocator typically will re-use storage.  I recommend, as Don Wakfield does, reading Doug Lea's Paper for discussions of the various allocation algorithms.

Comment: Thanks, Andy, for your kindly responses. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andy, though I'd say that the data structure returns memory *to* the heap when it is destructed.

Unless your allocator is playing tricks with mmap or the like, then you are probably using some variation of DLMalloc (even that can use mmap in some cases, but I understand it to be uncommon). Read [Doug Lea's paper](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) for some insight.

Comment: Thanks, Don. I am very clear what stl does behind the scenes. I just used their classes according to the instructions. If they did not release memory properly, is it a problem of the stl? Further more, if I commented out the TDM ().swap (my_map); or the swap in the for loop, 
the Memory usage after delete map is 203.53M. The Memory usage after delete map is reduced only when I use both. This is very interesting to me, and I do not understand why. Any idea on this? I am reading the article you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: I mean I am not very clear about what stl does behind the scenes :-)

Comment: Ke, your use of swap with maps is a time-honored tradition. I picked it up from Scott Meyer when he taught it at the company where I work. What I mean is that when you perform the swap, the original map's internal store (which is the space it allocated to hold all those vectors), gets returned to the heap. If you are not familiar with heaps, Linux dynamic memory or new and delete, you can have a lot of fun with an afternoon of Google ;^)~

Comment: Hi Don, I have had a lot of fun with this coding stuff :-). So the memory in the heap can be used for further usage without asking OS for memory, right? You know what, The input gzip file is just 12MB, but it said the required memory is 203MB. I have to reduce the memory usage since it may reach 40GB when I read all my input files (2GB in gzip). I can live with it if the memory usage is under 10GB. But the 40G is too much. Any comments or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Ke, sure, it is a 'heap of available memory'. As you get further in your studies, you will encounter things like fragmentation which can affect how efficient that memory re-use is. As for your application, I can't really comment on it. That sort of thing takes instrumentation, profiling and the like. More Googling! ;^)~

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Don. Wish you a nice weekend. I am going to dig into the problem :-)